# Dictionary.merging()... Can closure do per key selection? And, why is API declaration so different from example?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Swift Dictionary 'merging' function. I'm confused by the documentation, and I'd like some help understanding how to read that.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127173-merging

In the documentation, the API declaration looks like this:

```
func merging(_ other: [Key : Value], uniquingKeysWith 
   combine: (Value, Value) throws -> Value) rethrows -> [Key : Value]
```

It explicitly shows that the closure has a label 'uniquingKeysWith`, yet, the documented example doesn't refer to that closure argument label at all! In fact the example seems to ignore a lot of the API declaration (such as return values).

```
let dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
let otherDictionary = ["a": 3, "b": 4]

let keepingCurrent = dictionary.merging(otherDictionary)
      { (current, _) in current }
// ["b": 2, "a": 1]
let replacingCurrent = dictionary.merging(otherDictionary)
      { (_, new) in new }
// ["b": 4, "a": 3]
```

I'd like to do per-key processing in the closure, the example doesn't suggest ist's possible. Specifically, I want to drop nil values in `otherDictionary`, and override `dictionary` values with non-nil values.

I suppose I want to filter, and could actually `filter()` `otherDictionary` to drop keys with nil values before handing KVPs to the `merge` function, but I'd rather just do it in one closure if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127175-merging) is pretty clear. It says

> … the combine closure is called with the current and new values for any duplicate keys that are encountered.

Only the keys which occur in **both** dictionaries are being processed in the closure.

In this example the closure is called for the keys `a` and `b` and the higher value of `current` (representing `dictionary`) and `new` (representing `otherDictionary`) is returned respectively.

```
let dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 4, "c": 4]
let otherDictionary = ["a": 3, "b": 2, "d": 5]

let keepingHighest = dictionary.merging(otherDictionary)
{ (current, new) in
    print(current, new) // prints 4 2 and 1 3
    return max(current, new)
}

// ["c": 4, "b": 4, "d": 5, "a": 3]
```

`nil` values in a dictionary are fighting the system as according to the definition a `nil` value indicates a *missing key*.

Comment: Thanks for that! This seems to work. I tested it in playground: `dictA = dictB.merging(dictC.filter { $0.value != nil }) { ( _, new) in new }`.  But how is it that we omit the label `uniquingKeysWith:`?

Comment: This is the [Trailing Closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) syntax